# After XAMPP can't access to localhost (403)

Tags: apache-http-server, osx-mavericks, localhost, xampp

I've just got a MacBook Pro a few months ago. I've installed XAMPP on it.

After I googled a bit, I found OSX has its own apache service built in, so I removed XAMPP.

I've tried to configure my apache localhost, but it throws `403 Forbidden error` when I try to open `http://localhost/`, and I can't figure out why!

Can anyone give me help in setting up the in-built Apache Web Service on OSX?

**EDIT 1:** In terminal the `sudo tail /var/log/apache2/error_log` display this, after I try to reach `http://localhost/`:

```
[Sat Jun 21 12:07:02 2014] [error] [client ::1] (13)Permission denied: access to / denied (filesystem path '/Users/rgstudio/Documents/RGStudio') because search permissions are missing on a component of the path
[Sat Jun 21 12:07:02 2014] [error] [client ::1] (13)Permission denied: access to /favicon.ico denied (filesystem path '/Users/rgstudio/Documents/RGStudio') because search permissions are missing on a component of the path
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try the correct port number?

`http://localhost:80` or 
`http://localhost:443` or
`http://localhost:8080`

it could be any other port number depending on the configuration, see your main XAMPP window. check your `\xampp\apache\conf\httpd.conf` if you would like to change it.

if that doesn't get the problem fixed, try this

1. Open the `httpd-xampp.conf` file at the location `\xampp\apache\conf\httpd.conf` using a text editor
2. Search for the text **#New XAMPP security concept** and beneath that *find the line* **Deny from all**.
3. *Replace* the word **Deny** with **Allow** so that it becomes Allow from all
4. Now search the text  and between this opening tag line and its closing tag line , *add the line* **Require all granted** and save(overwrite) the file.
5. Now restart XAMPP and test.

Comment: I think you misunderstand me. I don't want to use XAMPP. I removed it from the computer, and I want to use the built in apache server.

Comment: what do you mean by "built in"? is it the Apache server that came along with XAMPP that you want to use?

Comment: I mean the OS X built in Apache server.

Comment: Sorry, I have no experience with Macs. But this might help, same problem [Starting built in Apache server in Mac OS X 10.9 (Mavericks)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20026702/starting-built-in-apache-server-in-mac-os-x-10-9-mavericks)